# C#: is there any better way to replace special character and compare

Tags: c#

I have 2 similar string except some special character. Is there a better way to compare and check for equality?

```
string str1 = "Hello (T) How";
string str2 = "Hello [T] How";

if (str1.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "") == str2.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Equal");
}
```

Comment: You can use Regex to match special character and replace it with space.

    using System;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
         
    public class Program
    {
     public static void Main()
     {
      string str1 = "Hello (T) How";
      string str2 = "Hello [T] How";
      
      Regex re = new Regex("[\\[\\]()]");
      str1 = re.Replace(str1, " ");
      str2 = re.Replace(str2 , " ");
        
      if(str1 == str2 )
       Console.WriteLine("Equal");
     }
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string str1 = "Hello (T) How";
      string str2 = "Hello [T] How";
      string str3 = "Hello [X] How";

      var compare1And2 = String.Compare(str1, str2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols);
      var compare1And3 = String.Compare(str1, str3, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols);

      System.Console.WriteLine(compare1And2); // 0 
      System.Console.WriteLine(compare1And3); // -1
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this simply by using Regular expressions.

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");
```

This will replace all your special characters from your string, in your case-

```
if(Regex.Replace(str1, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "").Equals(Regex.Replace(str2, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", ""))) 
{
    // Write code here
}
```

Also `Regex` class in available in `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
string str1 = "Hello (T) How";
string str2 = "Hello [T] How";

bool isEqual = string.Join("", str1.ToCharArray().Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray()) ==
string.Join("", str2.ToCharArray().Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray());
```

Basically what I am doing here is that I am selecting only all letters before comparing them.